# how to sum up value within one cell SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary, sum, frequency

I have some binary values such as 00, 0000, 001000.11111000, 1111100000

I need to sum it up so it turns into 0, 0, 1, 5, 5 ( sum 0s and 1s up)

how can we do that in SQL please?

Thanks

Comment: I think the answer to your question will depend on the version of SQL you are using.  By "version" I mean MySQL or SQL Server or something else.

Comment: SQL Server 12. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query. If needed convert it into function.

```
create function dbo.fnSumChars(@someInt VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @count INT = LEN(@someInt),
            @counter INT = 1

    DECLARE @Sum INT = 0

    WHILE @counter <= @count
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sum += CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(@someInt AS VARCHAR), @counter, 1) AS int)
        SELECT @counter += 1
    END

    RETURN @sum --5
END
```

This is the function and you can call this function like below

```
SELECT dbo.fnSumChars('1111100000')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but how can I turn it into a function?

Answer (score 0):

#### Assumption:

1. The binary values are stored as string.
2. Each value is in its own cell in a table. Something like:

   ```
   BinaryValues (Consider it a column name)
   00
   0000
   001000
   ```

   and so on.
3. You want to add up the individual digits to get the sum.
4. SQL Product you are usind supports functions, looping, string manipulation like substring, extracting string length etc. 
   As per my best knowledge these are primitives available in all SQL products.

#### Solution:

Write a function (call it by any name. Ex: **AddBinaryDigits**) which will take the binary value in string format as input. 
Inside the function and do a string manipulation. Extract each digit and add it up. Return the sum as result.
Call the function: 
If using binary values stored in a table:

```
SELECT AddBinaryDigits(BinaryValues) FROM <WhatEverTableName>
```

If using fixed value:

```
SELECT AddBinaryDigits('00')
SELECT AddBinaryDigits('0000')
SELECT AddBinaryDigits('001000')
```

and so on.

Edited to include the request to create function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION <funtionName>   
(
@ParameterName AS VARCHAR(expected string length like 10/15/20 etc.)
)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN   
    SQL Code to sum
    RETURN SummedUpValue
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are already in string format, this is the easiest:

```
select len(replace('1111100000', '0', ''))
```

No need for a function either, because it can be inlined in the query. Functions, even the light ones, incure perf penalty.